# Mutate subviews async

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with adding and removing views in background.

I tried `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadDataInScrollView) withObject:nil];`

And

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});
```

And everytime i get `Collection <CALayerArray: 0x165a7e50> was mutated while being enumerated.'`

Code:

```
- (void)loadDataInScrollView {

    int thresholdStart = currentPage * numberOfElementsPerLine - (numberOfPreloadedPages / 2) * numberOfElementsPerLine;
    int start = thresholdStart > 0 ? thresholdStart : 0;

    int thresholdEnd = currentPage * numberOfElementsPerLine + numberOfVisibleElements + (numberOfPreloadedPages / 2) * numberOfElementsPerLine;
    int end = thresholdEnd > numberOfElements ? numberOfElements : thresholdEnd;



    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

        [self createElementAtIndex:i];
//            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createElementAtIndex:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

        for (int i = TAG_CONFLICT; i < start + TAG_CONFLICT; i++) {
            [self removeElementAtIndex:i];
        }
        for (int i = end + TAG_CONFLICT; i < numberOfElements + TAG_CONFLICT; i++) {
            [self removeElementAtIndex:i];
        }

    }


    self.isLoaded = YES;

    NSLog(@"start: %d, end: %d", start, end);
}

- (void)removeElementAtIndex:(int)index {

    UIView *view = [base viewWithTag:index];
    if (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

}

- (void)createElementAtIndex:(int)index {

    if (![base viewWithTag:index+TAG_CONFLICT]) {
        int x = leftRightPadding + index % numberOfElementsPerLine * (sizeElement.width + flexibleSpace);
        int y = topBottomPadding + index / numberOfElementsPerLine * (sizeElement.height + flexibleSpace);
        UIView *element = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, sizeElement.width, sizeElement.height)];
        [self.dataSource gallery:self view:element atIndex:index];

        if (border) {
            element.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            element.layer.borderColor = [borderColor CGColor];
        }

        element.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(elementTapped:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

        [element addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        [element setTag:index+TAG_CONFLICT];
        [element setAlpha:0];

        [base addSubview:element];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            element.alpha = 1;
        }];
    }
}

#pragma mark - ScrollView delegates

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    initialOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    currentPage = (initialOffset - topBottomPadding) / (sizeElement.height + topBottomPadding);
    direction = initialOffset > base.contentOffset.y ? BOTTOM : TOP;

    [self loadDataInScrollView]; // Here i've tried different ways to send in background
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you what the problem is and what to do. You cannot mutate a mutable array while you are enumerating that array (i.e. in the middle of a for-loop). You need to walk through the array and make a *separate* nonmutable list (array) of the things you want to change. After the loop is completely over, do another loop where you use that list to make the changes.

Also, you must never touch the interface in a background thread. You are calling `loadDataInScrollView` in the background. Thus `loadDataInScrollView` calls `removeElementAtIndex` in the background. Thus `removeElementAtIndex` calls `removeFromSuperview` in the background - that is totally illegal.

So you're going to have to completely rearchitect your approach here on those two grounds.

Comment: I know that i am not allowed to touch the interface in background.. But it's a heavy job and it's moving slow while scrolling.. Do you have any ideea how to do that?

Comment: I don't know what it is you are trying to do, so no. You should NOT be doing any "heavy job" while scrolling, for exactly this reason. There have been lots of great WWDC videos in the past discussing how to scroll efficiently; you might watch some. Also, use Instruments to tell you exactly what's causing the slow frame rate.

Comment: +1 for both of Matt's points. Don't ever mutate a collection while enumerating it, and don't ever, under any circumstances, manipulate UI from a background thread. You can use code like performSelectorOnMainThread or similar GCD calls to make UI calls to the main thread from your background thread if needed.